# Wait for unknown pop-up window

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

I'm looking for a way to wait for a window to pop-up that you do not know the name. I'm looking for something like:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.new_window_is_opened((driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1]))))
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Handle multiple window in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10629815/handle-multiple-window-in-python)

Answer (score 2):

There is the relevant [`new_window_is_opened()` expected condition](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.new_window_is_opened):

```
handles = driver.window_handles
until(EC.new_window_is_opened(driver.window_handles))
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[-1])
```