# getwindowhandles in selenium

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium

Im getting: 
AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'getwindowhandles'

when trying

```
 Whandles = driver.getWindowHandles()
 print(Whandles)
```

these are my imports:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from ui.css import Ui_Dialog
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
import time
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: `driver.getWindowHandles()` of which Window? Where is the driver initialized & where is the Browser Window? Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Handle multiple window in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10629815/handle-multiple-window-in-python)

Comment: good questions for beginner in selenium & python .

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The exception is telling you that there is no method getWindowHandles() on the driver class. What you need is

```
Whandles = driver.window_handles
```

When you see this type of exception, do a `print(dir(driver))` to see what methods **are** supported by the class.