# Python switching windows with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

Could you help me with an advice? I'm doing some QA test and am testing a site. During the process, one by one windows in Chrome open and I'm trying to switch between these windows in Chrome. I don't succeed to switch to the third window. Can you help please? I'm using Pycharm and Selenium framework.

Here is the part of the Code where I ask your assistance:

```
second_login= webdriver.Ie()
second_login.maximize_window()
second_login.get('http://google.com')
print(second_login.title)
second_login.find_element_by_id('id1').click()
tab_now = second_login.window_handles[1]
second_login.switch_to.window(tab_now)
print(second_login.title)
log = second_login.find_element_by_id('id2')
log.send_keys('admin1')
pas=second_login.find_element_by_id('id3')
pas.send_keys('pas1')
logbutton=second_login.find_element_by_class_name('LoginButton')
logbutton.click()
second_login.implicitly_wait(3)
tab_after = second_login.window_handles[-1]
second_login.switch_to.window(tab_after)
second_login.find_element_by_id('id4').click()
print(second_login.title)
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

As described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29982298/2501723), you can do it by using window_handles and switch_to_window method.

Before clicking the link first window handle as

```
window_before = driver.window_handles[0]
```

Second window handle of newly opened window as

```
window_after = driver.window_handles[1]
```

I assume the third window would be

```
driver.window_nandles[2]
```

Also take a look [here](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/navigating.html#moving-between-windows-and-frames), you can loop trough windows, just break on the 3rd window and do whatever you want:

```
for handle in driver.window_handles:
    driver.switch_to_window(handle)
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks Slav, but I have another issue now, when I run the code, the first 2 windows are opening and for the third one here is the error I receive:  window_now = second_login.window_handles[2]
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Hi, what happens if you call again second_login.window_handles[1]