# Selenium not printing out the right URL

Tags: python, selenium

I'm practicing with selenium right now but I can't seem to get it to print the correct URL.

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
home_page = ''
driver.get(home_page)


time.sleep(15)
for i in range(1,9):
    listing_page = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="m_property_lst_cnt_realtor_more_'+str(i)+'"]').click()
    realtor_url = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="lblMediaLinks"]/a').click()
    print(driver.current_url)
    driver.get(home_page)
    time.sleep(5)
```

I need the URL of the webpage that opens up when selenium clicks on the element in realtor_url. It instead prints the URL of the first click from listing_page.

(Note: webpage that is opened from realtor_url is a completely different website, if that helps)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to switch to the newly opened window before printing the URL, then close the newly opened window and switch back to the original window.

```
// do the click that opens another window
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(lambda d: len(d.window_handles) == 2)
driver.switch_to_window(driver.window_handles[1])
print(driver.current_url)
driver.close()
driver.switch_to_window(driver.window_handles[0])
```

A couple other things...

1. `.click()` returns `void`, i.e. nothing, so there's nothing ever stored in `listing_page` or `realtor_url` variables.
2. `sleep()` is a bad practice. Don't use it. Google it to find out the details why. Replace `sleep()` with a relevant `WebDriverWait`.

Comment: What it's doing is clicking on a real estate listing then from that page, clicks on the agents website and prints out the URL of their web page. There are 9 listings on the page so it goes through the row and does this for each.

Comment: I see now. I missed the `i` in your first click statement. I added some details.

Comment: No worries, I tinkered with the wait time for the second URL but the issue is that print(driver.current_url) prints the URL from the first instance rather than from the new webpage that I want it to. Both your and Kiran's answers cleared up a lot of frustration! Thank you :)

Comment: If you still have issues with printing the wrong URL, you may need to use a wait to wait for the second window to open, e.g. `WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(lambda d: len(d.window_handles) == 2)`. Added this to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to change the "focus"of the window in order to print the correct url. The current window handler may be pointing to the previous click and not changed focus to the new window.
Try and get to change the "window handler". Every new window opened has a handler.

I hope this helps. [window_handles](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.window_handles) Or this [Handle multiple window in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10629815/handle-multiple-window-in-python)

EDIT:

The below should bring you to the latest open window.

```
driver.switch_to_window(driver.window_handles[-1])
```