# Controlling and automating a child browser window

Tags: python, automation

Suppose I access some applications through a VPN. Let's say a webbrowser like internet explorer is one of these applications. Using python's selenium package I can automate logging in to VPN and opening the internet application inside the VPN. Now the internet explorer window inside VPN opens.

So what I need to know is:

1. Is there any way by which I can control this new internet explorer through python' selenium package?
2. Is there any way to automate this child window using any other scripting language like Perl, tcl, vbscript etc?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Selenium provides methods to control the behavior of a separate child window that is spawned by another browser window. There are methods which allow you to jump into that window, perform some actions and then come back to the parent window that triggered the child window.

> Is there any way to automate this child window using any other
>   scripting language like Perl ,tcl,vbscript etc ?

As mentioned above, Selenium with Python should be good enough to automate the process in child window.

Adding a couple of links that may help you with this

1. [How to handle multiple windows Python Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10629815/handle-multiple-window-in-python)
2. [Handling multiple windows](https://seleniumwithjavapython.wordpress.com/selenium-with-python/switching-between-windows-and-alerts/)
3. [Link 3](http://allselenium.info/handling-multiple-windows-python-selenium/)

Comment: will it work if the child window is of a different browser . Like I opened citrix , and opened internet explorer inside that . How to control this ie window ?