# Selenium could not switch to newly opened Tab

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to create a tool that will automate the process of sharing video across multiple platforms and social media. I wanted to use Python and Selenium as a Webdriver to click on the share button on the YouTube video's webpage and then post it on several social media.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait, Select
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions
from main import wait_for_element
import time
import os

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--user-data-dir=PATH_2_CHROME_DATA")

browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path='PATH_2_CHROMEDRIVER.EXE')

def wait_for_element(browser, element, by_what):
    return WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located((by_what, element)))

def youtube(youtube_details):
    yt_url = youtube_details['yt_url']
    # YouTube Page
    browser.get(yt_url)

    share_btn = wait_for_element(browser,'//*[@id="button" and contains(@aria-label,"Share")]',By.XPATH)
    share_btn.click()

    reddit_btn = wait_for_element(browser,'//*[@id="target" and contains(@title,"reddit")]', By.XPATH)
    reddit_btn.click()

    community_dropdown = wait_for_element(browser,'#SHORTCUT_FOCUSABLE_DIV > div > div > div > div.s7pq5uy-1.hjrnH > div.s7pq5uy-5.ezjCpv > div.sdccme-0.kIpPAE > div > div.s1eg75c7-1.dsiNBS > div > div > div.s1u2j4lv-1.bTtqCO > input', By.CSS_SELECTOR)
    community_dropdown.send_keys('r/Bumble')                  

if __name__ == '__main__':
    youtube_details = {
        'yt_url':'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ',
    }
    youtube(youtube_details)
```

When the Webdriver click on the reddit share button, it opens a new tab which the driver isn't controlling. Thus, the driver could not locate the element on reddit webpage.

I tried adding the following line after clicking on the reddit share button to switch to the newly opened tab.

```
browser.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + Keys.TAB)
```

But it isn't working. I've also looked through several forum posts but none of which is exactly the problem I'm facing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Handle multiple windows in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10629815/handle-multiple-windows-in-python)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`chromedriver` generates window handle for each tab, use it to switch between the tabs as you switch between windows

```
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[-1])
```

Answer (score 0):

I use [`driver.switch_to_window`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/navigating.html#moving-between-windows-and-frames) to switch to a newly opened tab, and then back again.

Basically, I keep track of `driver.window_handles` before I do the action (e.g., button click), which opens the new tab.