# Download with python selenium

Tags: python, selenium, download

I want to download a file from a website. In the website I click on a button that opens a small sub-window, which has a button that downloads a file to the directory `path_here`when clicked. This is my solution:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

chrome_options = Options()

chrome_options.add_argument('--dns-prefetch-disable')
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {
  "download.default_directory": r'path_here',
  "download.prompt_for_download": False,
  "download.directory_upgrade": True,
  "safebrowsing.enabled": True
})
driver = webdriver.Chrome("./chromedriver", options=chrome_options)

website = "https://www.chess.com/ccc"
driver.get(website)  # loads the page
# This closes a sub-window that opens automatically
element = driver.find_element_by_class_name("form-button-component")
element.click()

driver.find_element_by_class_name("icon-download").click()
download = driver.find_element_by_class_name('download-pgn')
# Click to download
download.find_element_by_class_name("btn").click()
```

This should work, but does not download the file, as I expected. I add a screenshot for completeness:

[image: description]

The button is Download Game (PGN), whose text is obtained by `print(download.find_element_by_class_name("btn").text)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In the website I click on a button that opens a small sub-window

Here you've mentioned that you are opening a new sub window where you've to click the button to download. But you are not switching to that window. Hence not able to find that element.

Use `driver.window_handles` to get handle to the opened window and switch to that window using `driver.switch_to_window()` then try clicking on the button to download.

You can see how to handle multiple windows in python selenium in this stackoverflow [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10629815/handle-multiple-windows-in-python).

**EDIT:**

So it seems there were some issues in your code. Like the locator for download buttons next to chess board and the one after that were incorrect. I've corrected the locator's with proper `xpath` and also made little change in `chrome_options`. You just have to change the `download.defualt_directory` to a path in you machine and the below code will work:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

chrome_options = Options()

chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {
  "download.default_directory": r"C:\Users\Thanthu Nair\Downloads\Test",
  "download.prompt_for_download": False,
  "download.directory_upgrade": True,
  "safebrowsing.enabled": True
})
driver = webdriver.Chrome("./chromedriver", options=chrome_options)

website = "https://www.chess.com/ccc"
driver.get(website)  # loads the page
driver.maximize_window()

# This closes a sub-window that opens automatically
element = driver.find_element_by_class_name("form-button-component")
element.click()

download = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//i[@title='Download']")
download.click()

# Click to download
download.find_element_by_xpath("//button[normalize-space()='Download Game (PGN)']").click()
```

Comment: it is not a window per se, it is like a window within the main window, it's not like a pop up or something like that.

Comment: can you add a screenshot ?

Comment: I have added it

Comment: Did you check if it is in an <iframe>. I visited the url, I am not getting that window you have in your screenshot

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what an iframe is. If you visit the url you have to click on the download icon which is in the lower part of the right panel next to the big chess board.

Comment: So there were a few issue's, I've explained them in answer under edit, you can read that and update your code to get things working.