# Open a link from a list of links in new tab

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, firefox

I have a bunch of links in a list and I want to open each link in a different tab (only one window).  I know how to open a new tab in Selenium but for some reason, when I iterate over the list, all links get open in the same tab and I don't know what I am missing. Could anyone explain me what the error is and how I can fix it? I would really appreciate it.

```
from selenium import webdriver as wd
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

url_list = ["https://www.kdnuggets.com/2017/06/text-clustering-unstructured-data.html", "https://github.com/vivekkalyanarangan30/Text-Clustering-API/", "https://machinelearningblogs.com/2017/01/26/text-clustering-get-quick-insights-from-unstructured-data/", "https://machinelearningblogs.com/2017/06/23/text-clustering-get-quick-insights-unstructured-data-2/", "https://machinelearningblogs.com/2017/06/23/text-clustering-get-quick-insights-unstructured-data-2/"]


driver = wd.Firefox(executable_path="/usr/local/bin/geckodriver")


for url in url_list:
    body = driver.find_element_by_tag_name("body")
    body.send_keys(Keys.COMMAND + "t")
    driver.get(url)
```

Currently using python3.7, Firefox 65.0.1 and Selenium 3.141 on a Mac

Comment: If your `body.send_keys` call opens a new tab then perhaps you should switch to that newly opened "window" before calling `driver.get`. See [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10629815/handle-multiple-windows-in-python) on switching windows.

Comment: I did, but that did not resolve the problem. `driver.switch_to_window(driver.window_handles[-1])` didn't work

Comment: @CarolinaCárdenas Did new tab open?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you open a new tab it is a new window for webdriver which will have its unique handle. `driver.window_handles` holds the list of active windows, you can use this to switch to newly created window and perform tasks on it.

```
for url in url_list:
    body = driver.find_element_by_tag_name("body")
    body.send_keys(Keys.COMMAND + "t")
    driver.switch_to_window(driver.window_handles[-1])
    driver.get(url)
```

Note that you will be using the same variable `driver` to refer to the newly switched window, so if you close that window then you need to switch to an active window again to perform further tasks.

UPDATE:

If new tab is not opening with your code then you can also try this.

```
for url in url_list:
    driver.execute_script("window.open()")
    driver.switch_to_window(driver.window_handles[-1])
    driver.get(url)
```

Comment: This didn't work. All the links keep opening in the same tab.

Comment: Are new tabs opened? If not then check the updated answer.

Comment: send_keys Ctrl+T did NOT open a new tab on my machine (Chrome) so I tried `driver.execute_script("window.open()")` as @Kamal suggested and which does work and `driver.switch_to_window(driver.window_handles[-1])` does switch to the new tab and `driver.get("https://google.com")` does open google in the new tab. I follow the same steps for yahoo.com and again this opens in the new tab.

Comment: Hey @Kamal, the `driver.execute_script("window.open()")` did the trick, thank you very much! FYI it seems that `driver.switch_to_window` will get discontinuated, and the new one should be `driver.switch_to.window`. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

use window switching with commands

`one=driver.window_handles[0]` - set the name of the first window

`two=driver.window_handles[1]` - the name of the second window (after opening it)

`driver.switch_to.window(two)` - switch to the desired window

Comment: Isn't this similar to Kamal's answer?: `driver.switch_to_window(driver.window_handles[-1])`