# unable to access sign in with google alert on website using selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, element

I am attempting to create a script in which I sign in to a website with my google account, but I am having a major issue which I can't get my head around.

```
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver

from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
driver = webdriver.Chrome("/Users/vagif/Downloads/chromedriver")
driver.get('https://passport.alibaba.com/icbu_login.htm?return_url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.alibaba.com%2F')
driver.implicitly_wait(3)
google = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@attr-type="google"]')
google.click()

time.sleep(1)
actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.key_down(Keys.COMMAND + '~').perform()
time.sleep(1)
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@type="email"]')

element.send_keys('leine.tee1@gmail.com')
time.sleep(1)
next = driver.find_element_by_class_name('RveJvd').click()
time.sleep(1)
password = driver.find_element_by_class_name('whsOnd').send_keys('***password***')
next = driver.find_element_by_class_name('RveJvd').click()
```

My problem is that the code works fine up until the sign in with google popup appears. After that, I receive an error saying that the element was not located. Any help would really be appreciated thank you all!

Comment: You might want to change your Google password now

Comment: @Ollie Thanks did not even notice

Comment: Looks like a new window? Have you tried switching window (or frame) and then trying to access the elements.

Comment: @demouser123 I have tried switch_to_alert() but it did not work. Do you know any other methods?

Comment: It is not an alert. Try switching to a window or an iframe. See the documentation for more usage.

Comment: @demouser123 I tried element = driver.switch_to_frame(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@type="email"]'))
but it failed

Comment: Please see this [link](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/navigating.html#moving-between-windows-and-frames).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @demouser123 and [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10629815/handle-multiple-windows-in-python) I was able to solve the problem.

By adding the following code:

```
window_before = driver.window_handles[0]
window_after = driver.window_handles[1]
driver.switch_to_window(window_after)
```

I was successfully able to switch tabs. Here is my full code:

```
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
driver = webdriver.Chrome("/Users/vagif/Downloads/chromedriver")
driver.get('https://passport.alibaba.com/icbu_login.htm?return_url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.alibaba.com%2F')
driver.implicitly_wait(3)
google = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@attr-type="google"]')
google.click()

window_before = driver.window_handles[0]
window_after = driver.window_handles[1]
driver.switch_to_window(window_after)
time.sleep(1)

time.sleep(1)
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@type="email"]')

element.send_keys('leine.tee1@gmail.com')
time.sleep(1)
next = driver.find_element_by_class_name('RveJvd').click()
time.sleep(2)
password = driver.find_element_by_class_name('whsOnd').send_keys('****password')
next = driver.find_element_by_class_name('RveJvd').click()
```

Thanks all for the help!