# Trouble locating element with selenium and determing ID

Tags: python, html, selenium, css-selectors

Receiving the error: "selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element:"

```
browser.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@id='email']")
browser.find_element_by_id("email")
browser.find_element_by_id("input")
browser.find_element_by_class("inputtext")
browser.find_element_by_class_name("_55r1")
browser.find_element_by_class_name("login")
browser.find_element_by_class_name("login_page")
browser.find_element_by_class_name('login_form_label')
browser.find_element_by_class_name('label.login_form_label')
browser.find_element(By.XPATH, "//label[text()='Email or Phone']")
browser.find_element_by_id("email_container")
```

Even added an browser
    .implicity_wait(10)

All yielding the same error.

Any ideas?

[image: Source code]

Comment: The correct solution was a handler issue with a new window: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10629815/how-to-switch-to-new-window-in-selenium-for-python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Make sure that the element you're looking for doesn't belong to an [iframe](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe), otherwise you will have to use [switch_to_frame](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.switch_to_frame) function in order to change the context to the relevant iframe prior to locating the element
2. Make sure that the element you're looking for isn't hidden in the [Shadow DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_shadow_DOM), otherwise you will have to locate the relevant [ShadowRoot](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ShadowRoot) and cast it to the [WebElement](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement), once done use [WebElement.find_element_by](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.find_element) function to locate the element (not browser.find_element_by)
3. In any case I would recommend using [Explicit Wait](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits) as it might be the case the element is not immediately available in [DOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model) (for example it's being loaded via an [AJAX](https://experitest.com/selenium-testing/ajax_technology_selenium/) call)

   ```
   email = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "email")))
   ```

Comment: I accepted to close the topic, or should there be another course of action for this thread?