# How to find URL of web page opened by clicking link?

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, geturl

My scenario is:
I opened a webpage (it has different links) and clicked on a link randomly.
Now I want to get the URL of that webpage opened.

I searched a lot and found the same answer everywhere which I tried.

```
driver.get(url)
driver.current_url
```

It every time returns me the URL of the main webpage, not that which is opened by clicking a link randomly. 
What I have observed is, such is happening because on clicking link new webpage opens up in a new tab and current_url returns me URL of the page that is on the first tab. Any solution to this problem?

Comment: Take a look to [switch to new window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10629815/how-to-switch-to-new-window-in-selenium-for-python) and [how to switch to the new browser window which opens after click on the button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9588827/how-to-switch-to-the-new-browser-window-which-opens-after-click-on-the-button)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to work with new tab you have to switch driver to it.

You can use Selenium methods to check current window and move to another one:

```
driver.window_handles
```

to find a list of window handles and after try to switch using following methods.

```
- driver.switch_to.active_element      
- driver.switch_to.default_content
- driver.switch_to.window
```

Answer (score 0):

I would say you need to gather URL from link itself. I mean "href" attribute. If there is just some onClick event and URL is generated dynamically you need to adjust this function to pass url where you need it.