# how can I get the next page's reviews with selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

i'm trying to scrape more than 10 pages of reviews from https://www.innisfree.com/kr/ko/ProductReviewList.do

However when i move to the next page and try to get the new page's reviews, i still get the first page's reviews only.

i used driver.execute_script("goPage(2)") and also time.sleep(5) but my code only gives me the first page's reviews.

''' i did not use for-loop just to see whether the results are different between page1 and page2'''
''' i imported beautifulsoup and selenium'''

here is my code:

```
  url = "https://www.innisfree.com/kr/ko/ProductReviewList.do"

  chromedriver = r'C:\Users\hhm\Downloads\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe'

  driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)

  driver.get(url)


  print("this is page 1")

  driver.execute_script("goPage(1)")

  nTypes = soup.select('.reviewList ul .newType div[class^=reviewCon] .reviewConTxt')


  for nType in nTypes:

         product = nType.select_one('.pdtName').text

         print(product)


 print('\n')

 print("this is page 2")

 driver.execute_script("goPage(2)")

 time.sleep(5)

 nTypes = soup.select('.reviewList ul .newType div[class^=reviewCon] .reviewConTxt')


 for nType in nTypes:

         product = nType.select_one('.pdtName').text

         print(product)
```

Comment: any help would be very, very appreciated. thank you.

Comment: where did you assign `soup`? and did you re-assign soup after you call `goPage(2)`. oh and please remove extra blank lines

Comment: if you're using selenium, just have it click on the "next" button?

Answer (score 0):

If your second page open as new window then you need to switch to another page and switch your selenium control to another window

Example:

```
# Opens a new tab
self.driver.execute_script("window.open()")

# Switch to the newly opened tab
self.driver.switch_to.window(self.driver.window_handles[1])
```

Source:

[How to switch to new window in Selenium for Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10629815/how-to-switch-to-new-window-in-selenium-for-python)

https://www.techbeamers.com/switch-between-windows-selenium-python/

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code.You need to click on each pagination link to reach to next page.you will get all 100 review comments.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
url = "https://www.innisfree.com/kr/ko/ProductReviewList.do"
chromedriver = r'C:\Users\hhm\Downloads\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)
driver.get(url)

for i in range(2,12):
   time.sleep(2)
   soup=BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,'html.parser')
   nTypes = soup.select('.reviewList ul .newType div[class^=reviewCon] .reviewConTxt')
   for nType in nTypes:
      product = nType.select_one('.pdtName').text
      print(product)
   if i==11:
    break
   nextbutton=WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//span[@class='num']/a[text()='" +str(i)+"']")))
   driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();",nextbutton)
```

Comment: you really helped me a lot!! Thank you sooo much.