# Using IE WebDriver in Python often window handles are same

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, internet-explorer-11

```
base_handle = browser.current_window_handle
#some action to open another window
if len(browser.window_handles) == 2:
    new_window_handle = browser.window_handles[1]
```

Now when I print both of these handles, it works great most of the time, however, once in a while the handles are same for both windows. And I am not able to solve it. Let me know if I need to share more

Comment: You could collect the window handles every time when opening a new tab/window, then execute the `switch_to_window` method to move to the window you want. You could refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10629815/how-to-switch-to-new-window-in-selenium-for-python/29982298#29982298) about switching between old and new windows.

Comment: Thanks Yu.  However, I am doing that already, also, what the other person has recommended in this thread below.  It not that the code is not working, it works.  My question why out of 10 times 1 or 2 times the handle for base and new window is same?

Comment: Then I think you should add breakpoints in your code and check the code line by line to see if there's any difference when the issue occurs, like when collecting the window handles. Or if the handles are the same, then reopen the window.

Answer (score 1):

The order of the handles in `browser.window_handles` is not guaranteed. You need to add a check before switching

```
base_handle = browser.current_window_handle
for handle in browser.window_handles:
    if handle != base_handle:
        new_window_handle = handle
```