# I get errors when i try to input username and password with selenium using python

Tags: python, selenium

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys


driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://cstutil.it.siu.edu/CSRfrontend/')

link = driver.find_element_by_link_text(
 '>>SSL Certificate Signing Request/C-S-C Authorization Submission<<')
link.click()

username = driver.find_element_by_id("userNameInput")
username.clear()
username.send_keys("")

password = driver.find_element_by_name("Password")
password.clear()
password.send_keys("")

login_button = driver.find_element_by_id("submitButton")
login_button.click()
```

Here is my code, I am trying to input username and password using Selenium. But I get this 
 error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[id="userNameInput"]"}
```

Comment: Try using Xpath method, I find it more effective.

Comment: On clicking said link, a new window opens and then loads username and password fields. see if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/q/10629815/7964299

Comment: Alright, what is your question?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the first click. When the below line executes, it actually opens new tab.

```
link = driver.find_element_by_link_text(
 '>>SSL Certificate Signing Request/C-S-C Authorization Submission<<')
link.click()
```

So, you need to switch to the current new window, i have added 2 lines of code,  have a look.

```
window_after = driver.window_handles[1]
driver.switch_to.window(window_after)
```

Full code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='D:\chromedriver.exe')

driver.get(
 'https://cstutil.it.siu.edu/CSRfrontend/')
time.sleep(2)

link = driver.find_element_by_link_text(
 '>>SSL Certificate Signing Request/C-S-C Authorization Submission<<')
link.click()
time.sleep(2)
window_after = driver.window_handles[1]
driver.switch_to.window(window_after)
username = driver.find_element_by_id("userNameInput")
username.clear()
username.send_keys("")
time.sleep(2)
password = driver.find_element_by_name("Password")
password.clear()
password.send_keys("")
time.sleep(2)
login_button = driver.find_element_by_id("submitButton")
login_button.click()
```

Answer (score 0):

this error is showing because of new tab open. After click on Link it open in a new tab. Please use this code, this will be working correctly.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys


driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://cstutil.it.siu.edu/CSRfrontend/')

link = driver.find_element_by_link_text(
 '>>SSL Certificate Signing Request/C-S-C Authorization Submission<<')
link.click()
#Switch previous tab to new tab
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1]) 
username = driver.find_element_by_id("userNameInput")
username.clear()
username.send_keys("")

password = driver.find_element_by_name("Password")
password.clear()
password.send_keys("")

login_button = driver.find_element_by_id("submitButton")
login_button.click()
```