# Browser window closes as another opens when using Python Selenium Chromedriver

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I’m trying to automate web browsing with Python (2.7) / Selenium / Chromedriver but having a peculiar behavior when opening more than one site (browser window) in succession.  As a new browser window opens, a previously-opened one closes for some reason.  Is this a garbage collection issue?  Is there a way to force all browser windows to stay open? Here is a sample:

```
import sys
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get("http://google.com")
driver.get("http://amazon.com")
driver.get("http://ebay.com")
```

Answer (score 1):

Issue here is you are hitting multiple URLs in same tab. Its like clicking a new link inside a page which open the new page in same tab.What you need is to open seperate tab for each url.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("http://google.com")

#Open 2nd Tab
driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.COMMAND + 't') 
driver.get("http://amazon.com")

#Open 3rd Tab
driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.COMMAND + 't') 
driver.get("http://ebay.com")
```

**Or** if you want to open **separate windows** then you can create 3 instances of chrome driver and open separate urls in all of them.

```
driver1 = webdriver.Chrome()
driver2 = webdriver.Chrome()
driver3= webdriver.Chrome()

driver1.get("http://google.com")
driver2.get("http://amazon.com")
driver3.get("http://ebay.com")
```

**Note :**

I believe your next question will be how to work with different tabs. Follow below link:
[How to switch to new window in Selenium for Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10629815/how-to-switch-to-new-window-in-selenium-for-python)

Comment: Thanks, very helpful....one question though...is there a way to assign a window handler to each tab as you open it?  I know you can "get" a window handler with "driver.window_handles[index number here]" but the tricky part is that the "current" handler remains with the original (first) window opened unless you deliberately switch it with "driver.switch_to.window."  Assigning each window handler a variable name as it is opened would make it easy to keep track of which window is which.

Comment: You can store a reference to window handle using statement win1= driver.window_handles[0], win2 = driver.window_handles[1], win3 = driver.window_handles[2]. Now you can use these references to switch to any window like driver.switch_to_window(win2) . Also please accept the answer if it helps you solve your issue.