# How to scroll down child/pop-up window using Selenium in Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, scroll, instagram, childwindow

I am working on Instagram Bot using Python language and Selenium.

I am facing issue in scrolling down the pop-up window.
Using basic Javascript code for scrolling,
i.e

driver.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0,500)","")

it could only scroll the main window, not the child window(that needs to be scrolled)

I have attached a detailed picture of what I want.

[image]

Comment: you need to switch to the popup first: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10629815/how-to-switch-to-new-window-in-selenium-for-python

Comment: I tried but it is showing..
"List Index out of range" for driver.window_handles[1]

Here is the code:
window_before = driver.window_handles[0]

Following_Window=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(@href,'/following')]").click() 
---------
window_after = driver.window_handles[1]