# multiple chrome windows with webdriver python

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I would like to open multiple chrome windows. Once they open, however, they close at the end of the for loop. can anyone help me? thank you so much

```
for i in range(numeroTask):
    i = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)   
    i.get("https://www.youtube.com/")
```

Comment: Does this answer it https://stackoverflow.com/a/39037983/7746992 ?

Comment: I don't need to perform any actions on newly opened windows. I would just open a specific number of  windows and keep them open until the program ends

Comment: Do you need all of them to open a certain url? Bc opening a url is an action on a newly opened window.

Comment: yes, all windows must show the same url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you can do it. I'm using `window.open()` to open a new tab and then `driver.switch_to.window` to switch to it, so you can open a url.

```py
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

windows_count = 3

for i in range(windows_count):
    # Opens a new tab
    driver.execute_script("window.open()")
    # Switch to the newly opened tab
    driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[i])
    # Navigate to new URL in new window
    driver.get("https://youtube.com")

# Close all tabs:
driver.quit()
```

Hopefully this helps, good luck!

*Updated, way to do it with multiple chrome windows:*

```py
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

windows_count = 3

for i in range(windows_count):
    # Opens a new tab
    driver.execute_script('window.open("https://youtube.com", "_blank", "resizable=yes, scrollbars=yes, titlebar=yes, width=800, height=900, top=10, left=10");')

# Close all windows:
driver.quit()
```

Comment: thank you so much for your answer! But I want to open a lot of chrome windows not tabs in the same browser windows

Comment: Oh, I see. You can do anything with that JS really. I updated my answer with another option. It's working super quick, so probably add `sleep`s if you actually want to see what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

DO you want to open simultaneously? Then you should try threads, async functions.

Comment: yes simultaneously and then keep them open until I close the program