# Selenium keyboard.send key to a specific windows only

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

I have my code working on selenium but the problem is that when the code is running I can't switch to another chrome windows because it will send keybord key to the new one.
I need to send the key only to a specific windows where the code is running

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver')
driver.get ("mywebsite link")
        

        sleep(1)
        keyboard.send('l')
        sleep(0.5)
        keyboard.send('t')
        sleep(0.5)
        keyboard.send('enter')
        time.sleep(0.5)
```

Comment: what is keyboard.send?

Comment: when you are on twitter you can click l for like and t for retweet

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to switch to new window in Selenium for Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10629815/how-to-switch-to-new-window-in-selenium-for-python)

Comment: No basically, I don't need to switch the windows I want to execute my keyboard key to windows I have open only, because if I open a notepad for example it will send key to the notepad

Answer (score 0):

So I had a similar issue to this a while back.  The issue that you are running into is that you need to make sure that you are working with the correct window handle.

Your answer should be pretty easily solved here:
[How to switch to new window in Selenium for Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10629815/how-to-switch-to-new-window-in-selenium-for-python)