# How to handle appeared browser window with selenium Python?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

[image]

For example Selenium works on one google chrome browser and after some processes opens confirmation window like in picture another (smaller) google  chrome browser. And I can't find solution to switch to that another window.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to switch to new window in Selenium for Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10629815/how-to-switch-to-new-window-in-selenium-for-python)

Comment: When I use print(driver.current_window_handle) it shows only one.

Comment: It will only show one because only one window handle can be active at a time. Study and apply the code snippet that's here: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/webdriver/browser_manipulation/#switching-windows-or-tabs

Comment: Thanks, that solved my problem.