# Print to pdf or take screenshot of newly opened tab selenium

Tags: selenium

i am using selenium to open a site but inside site there is a hyperlink that opens a new tab. how can i take screenshot of that newly opened tab by navigating to it.

eg

```
import selenium.webdriver
import selenium.common

options = selenium.webdriver.firefox.options.Options()
# options.headless = True
with selenium.webdriver.Firefox(options=options) as driver:
    driver.get('url')
    time.sleep(2)
    root=driver.find_element_by_tag_name('html')
    root.screenshot('full page screenshot
```

But it does not work with new opened tab

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to switch to that window/tab to interact with it.
[how-to-switch-to-new-window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10629815/how-to-switch-to-new-window-in-selenium-for-python)

```
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1]) #1 being the second window
```